# gulp.series() not function when running multiple tasks

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

I am trying to run multiple gulp tasks one after another in synchronised fashion

but i got the following error

> TypeError: gulp.series is not a function

**Code**

```
gulp.task('default',function () {
    gulp.watch('resources/assets/js/components/*.js', function() {
        gulp.series('scripts','compress');
    });
})
```

Comment: Which version of gulp do you use?

Comment: Using Latest gulp

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to use **gulp.series** and **gulp.parallel** you need gulp **4.0**.

To get 4.+ which is technically in beta but has been around for a long time, use gulp **v4**

```sh
npm i gulp@4.0.0-alpha.2
```

**Update 13 July 2020**

Gulp v4 was released December 2018

```sh
npm i gulp@4.0.0 --save-dev
```

Comment: Let me try your answer

Comment: I'v the same problem gulp version is 3.9.1

Comment: What @Kirill is saying is that you need at least gulp4 to use gulp.series so use his second npm to get 4.0.....

Comment: Thank you! npm i gulp@4.0.0 --save-dev solved my issue.

Comment: node version is another thing to consider. node 8 + gulp 4 has some issues...

Answer (score 0):

Also you may install gulp version 4 using:

```
npm i gulpjs/gulp#4.0 --save-dev
```